# refrescar while cuando haya nuevos post (datos en la base de datos)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdo

hola una pregunta hay alguna forma de refrescar el while sin tener que recargar la pagina para mostrar los datos incertados en la base de datos mediante PDO?

estoy creando una pagina como twitter y quiero hacer el sistema de optencion de post sin recargar la web

Mi codigo para optener los datos es el siguiente

```php
<?php   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web;charset=utf8mb4;',"root","");
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC");
        $sql->execute();
        while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

          echo '<li class="rv b agz">
            <img
              class="bos vb yb aff"
              src="img/avatar/default.png">
            <div class="rw">
              <div class="bpb">
                <small class="acx axc">'.$result['time_date_post'].'</small>
                <h6>'.$result['usuario'].'</h6>
              </div>

              <p>';


            echo $result['cuerpo'];

              echo '</p>';
              if ($result['image'] == "") {

              }else {
                echo '<div class="boy" data-grid="images">
                <img style="display: inline-block; width: 466px; height: 451px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-width="640" data-height="640" data-action="zoom" src="'.$result['image'].'">
                </div>';

              }
            echo "</div>
          </li>";
                 }
        ?>
```

> Actualizo

Segun me comentaron abajo me encontré con este código pero mi problema es que refresca todos los post mi meta es que se actualice sin que desaparezcan los post anteriores que se publicaron en la web
hay alguna forma de hacer eso?
ya que seria molesto que refresque a cada rato

```
(function($)
{
  $(document).ready(function()
  {<br>
      $.ajaxSetup(
      {
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function() {
              $('#content').hide();
              $('#loading').show();
          },
          complete: function() {
              $('#loading').hide();
              $('#content').show();
          },
          success: function() {
              $('#loading').hide();
              $('#content').show();
          }
      });
      var $container = $("#content");
     $container.load("post-data.php");
      var refreshId = setInterval(function()
      {
        $container.load('post-data.php');
      }, 9000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Para eso vas a tener que emplear AJAX

Comment: Una forma sería, como recomienda el compañero, usando AJAX de forma que cada cierta cantidad de tiempo, haga una consulta de forma interna y en caso de que haya cambios en la base de datos ir actualizando el contenido del "timeline".

Comment: @lepeman y como puedo pasar este codigo a Ajax no tengo mucha idea de js

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar AJAX y responder en JSON pero deberás dividir en dos archivos.

```php
   <?php 
    // .. post.php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog;charset=utf8mb4;',"root","rootroot");
    $limite = 5;
    if(isset($_GET['limite'])){
      $limite = $_GET['limite'];
    }
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC limit $limite");
    $sql->execute();
    $response = [];
    while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
       $response[] = ['id'=>$result['id'], 'cuerpo'=>$result['contenido']];
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Ahora para el ..home.php

```html
<head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="loading"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
       var $contend = $('#contend'); // el div contendio
    var $loading = $('#loading'); // el loading
    var cargando = false; // para controlar la carga
    var limite = 5; // cantidad de post inicial
    var postsListados = new Array(); 
    var scrollTop = 0; // para controllar el scroll

    function handlerLoadPost(){
      $loading.show('fast');
      if (cargando === false ){ // carga solo si no hay una petición pendiente
        getPost();
      } 
    }

    function getPost(){
      cargando = true;
      $.get( "post.php", { limite } )
        .done(function( data ) {
          // eliminar los post ya visualizados
          data = data.filter(function(post){
          let nuevo = true;
          postsListados.forEach((elpost)=>{
            if(elpost.id === post.id){
              nuevo = false;
            } 
          });
          return nuevo;
        })
      // agregar los post faltantes
        addPost(data);
      })
      .fail(function( data ) {
        $contend.show('slow');
        $loading.show('fast');
        cargando = false;
        // para poder Ejecutar en stackoverflow
        let idRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        data = [{ id: idRandom , cuerpo: 'demo '+idRandom },
                { id: 2, cuerpo: 'demo'}];
        addPost(data);
         // borra esta lineas en produccion
      })
    }

    function addPost(data){
        data.forEach(post => {
           addElementPost(post)
        });
      // merge nuevos post
        Array.prototype.push.apply(postsListados, data);
        cargando = false;
        limite += 3;
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop)
        $loading.hide('fast');
         console.log(postsListados);
    }
  
    function addElementPost(element){
      $('#contend').prepend('<div class="post">'+element.cuerpo+'</div>');
    }

    function infinitiScrollLoading(){
      $(window).scroll(function () { 
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollTop >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10){
          handlerLoadPost()
        }
      })
    }

  // FINALMENTE LLAMO LOS METODOS
  handlerLoadPost()
  infinitiScrollLoading()
    </script>
</body>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad. Suerte

Comment: Nop no me cargan los post, muchas gracias

Comment: @Max He actualizado el código usando el método $.get de jquery, ademas ademas de una técnica llamada infiniti scroll loading usando el método  `  infinitiScrollLoading()`  revisa, espero te sea de utilidad. Suerte

Comment: hum sigue sin cargar aqui te dejo los archivos cargados a un server https://azuranetwork.tk/test-post.php https://azuranetwork.tk/test-post-data.php

Comment: No estas haciendo la petición, no es necesario que encierres en `(function(data){` :

Así esta y no funciona:
```<script> (function(data){ 
    var $content....
     ... el esto del codigo..
   handlerLoadPost()
   infinitiScrollLoading()
  });..
</script>```

Déjalo así:

```<script>var $content ...
   ... el esto del codigo..
   handlerLoadPost()
   infinitiScrollLoading()
</script>```